# Output all duplicate rows (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which holds what I consider duplicate rows. the values in these records may not be exactly the same, but it’s been calculated that they’re possible duplicates by fuzzy logic. For example:

```
RecordCD    key_in  key_out
---------------------------
1           1       2
2           2       2
3           3       3
4           4       6
5           5       5
6           6       6
7           7       7
8           8       11
9           9       9
10          10      10
11          11      11
```

`key_in` column has a unique ID of the record.

`key_out` column has a possible duplicate if it’s not equal to `key_in`

I need my output to look like this and list all of the possible duplicates:

```
RecordCD    key_in  key_out
---------------------------
1           1       2
2           2       2
4           4       6
6           6       6
8           8       11
11          11      11
```

but I’m struggling to construct a query that would do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like if there is a mismatch between `key_in`, `key_out` you want to pull all rows where `key_in` has either value`

I would create a temp table with all values in rows with mismatched `key_in`, `key_out`, call this value `bad_match`

If either of your `key_in`, `key_out` values match this value, include it in output

```
select mytable.* from mytable 
where key_in  in 
(select key_in bad_match from mytable where key_in <> key_out
union all
select key_out from mytable where key_in <> key_out);
```

This [sample](http://tpcg.io/Smq33t) builds your schema and returns the desired output

Comment: Hi @EoinS, yes your query works well, but I'm facing the same exact issue as I did with Gordon's answer above. Both of your queries return the same # of records which is good, but the resultset is not ordered/grouped the way I want it (group possible duplicates together in consecutive rows). The reason it actually groups them properly in your example is because I listed them in the proper order when in fact they're randomly positioned in the table. Thank you!

Comment: xQbert above was kind enough to sort (pun intended) this out for me. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.key_out = t.key_out and t2.key_in <> t.key_in
             )
order by t.key_out;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b8d5d12ec59895a527e35943f9c4e6e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, looks like this might work. Is it possible to output the rows grouping them by possible duplicates like I have them listed in my question? The way you have it, it would just randomly order the output. For example, I might have 3 possible duplicates and 1st one would be in row 10, 2nd one in row 520 and the 3rd one in row 20,145. I want them to be output in the consecutive rows (like rows 10, 11, and 12). Like I said, they're not exact duplicates so it's hard to order them by any specific field (fuzzy logic compares about 5 fields).  Thanks!

Comment: @tony `order by t.key_out, t.key_in`

Comment: @xQbert Works! Thank you!